# Laravel HasMany with included current Model on same Table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to have a method (with the possiblity to eager load) to return all users which are connected via `user_collection_uuid` including the current user. If the `user_collection_id` is not set it should at least return the current user.

The method I'm using (null values are automatically filtered due to `hasMany`):

```
class User extends Model {
    
    ...
    
    public function userInCollection(): HasMany
    { 
        return $this
           ->hasMany(User::class, 'user_collection_uuid', 'user_collection_uuid')
           ->orWhere('id', $this->id);
    }

    ...
}
```

It works if the method is called directly but not eager/lazy loaded:

```
$user->userInCollection()->get()->count() // Collection count returns 1
```

The following Code should do the same except it is resolved via LazyLoading or EagerLoading. However this returns 0.

```
$user->userInCollection->count() // Collection count returns 0
```

It seems like the User which calls the HasMany method is filtered from the result.
Is there another method to do this or am I missing something? Is this the desired behaviour?

Laravel 8.26.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use your `$this` context in a relationship.

the easiest way to do this would be to use a custom attribute :

```
    public function userInCollection(): HasMany
    { 
        return $this
           ->hasMany(User::class, 'user_collection_uuid', 'user_collection_uuid');
    }

    public function getUsersInCollectionAttribute()
    { 
        return $this->userInCollection->push($this);
    }
```

you can then do this :

```
$user = User::with('userInCollection')->find($id);
$user->users_in_collection;
```

Comment: Thank you. I think you should remove the `orWhere` in your answer since you mentioned that I cannot use `$this` in a relationship. If i understand the code correctly.

Comment: Yes my bad, I edited my answer :) don't forget to mark the answer as resolve :)